# View changes size depending on device screen size, but should have a fixed size

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

[image]

I have created an orange circle using a UIView100 height and 100 width with a radius of 50. This was done in the 4 inch setup.
When i move up to the 4.7inch or higher the circle becomes distorted. 
What do i do  so that the circle doesn't get distorted when displayed on larger devices?

Comment: how did you create that circle?  programmatically (via code) or only in your storyboard / xib file?  are there AutoLayout constraints you're using?

Comment: I entered the width and height in the properties inspector on the right. I then added the radius programmatically. Yes I hit the auto layout button and this is what Ive ended up with. The circle is in the right place but warps when placed on larger devices.

Comment: Edit your question to show a screenshot of the layout constraints on that circle UIView.  I suspect you have a fixed constraint on the bottom of that UIView that's causing it to be stretched, and you'll likely be seeing a "broken constraint" warning in the Xcode console because it can't do both the bottom constraint and the height constraint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I guess you used Xcode's “Reset to Suggested Constraints” option, like this:

[image: reset to suggested constraints]

When you do that, Xcode guesses what constraints you want. Unfortunately, in your case, it guessed wrong. It did create the centering constraints you wanted, but it did **not** create the width and height constraints you wanted. Instead it created leading edge and top edge constraints, like this:

[image: edge constraints]

So when you load your scene on a larger device, in order to satisfy those constraints, auto layout has to make the view larger, like this:

[image: resized]

To fix this, you need to delete the edge constraints:

[image: deleting edge constraints]

And add width and height constraints:

[image: adding width and height constraints]

So your final constraints on the subview look like this:

[image: final constraints]

With these constraints, when you load your scene on a larger device, the subview will stay centered and not change size:[image]

Comment: The best answer I've seen for a question, keep up the good work man.

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting you used a fixed corner radius to make a circular UIView (which would have a constraint for 1:1 aspect ratio too). Just make it so the radius of the corners is calculated somewhere where the right dimensions for the view can be known. viewDidLayoutSubviews is a good place as it'll take care of other resizes like screen rotation.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.circleView.layer.cornerRadius = self.circleView.frame.size.width / 2 // Assumes width == height because of 1:1 aspect ratio constraint
}
```

Alternatively don't make the size of your view depend on the width or height of the screen (i.e. remove constraints to the sides, center it and give it a fixed width and height)